# How to change the version of Python catkin uses

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to create a package with `catkin_create_pkg` but it is failing with this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File
> "/usr/local/bin/catkin_create_pkg",
> line 10, in 
> from catkin_pkg.package_templates import create_package_files,
> PackageTemplate ImportError: No module
> named 'catkin_pkg'

I think this is because it is trying to use Python 3 rather than Python 2. (running `python -c "import catkin_pkg"` works, but running `python3 -c "import catkin_pkg"` gives the import error)

Is there a nice way to switch it to always use Python 2 instead (the default Python on my system, and the one I prefer to use)? I just installed it with apt-get following the tutorials. Other stuff like `catkin_make` and `catkin_init_workspace` work fine, `catkin_create_pkg` was the first command I ran into that didn't work.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223701/how-to-change-the-version-of-python-catkin-uses/) by [Albatross](https://answers.ros.org/users/4920/albatross/) on ROS Answers with karma: 157 on 2016-01-08

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-01-08**:
Which versions of Linux and ROS are you using? The version of catkin_create_pkg that you're calling is in /usr/local; how did you install it?

**Comment by [Albatross](https://answers.ros.org/users/4920/albatross/) on 2016-01-08**:
I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 with ROS Indigo. I think installed it with `apt-get install python-catkin-pkg`, I also did an install of `ros-indigo-desktop-full` earlier when going through the tutorials, which may have included it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've confirmed that catkin_create_pkg is included as part of the `catkin_pkg` python package (which you can install on Ubuntu through the `python-catkin-pkg` apt package). This means that if you have `python-catkin-pkg` installed, you should have `catkin_create_pkg` in `/usr/bin`

Since your version of `catkin_create_pkg` appears to be located in `/usr/local/bin`, I suspect you ALSO installed `catkin_pkg` though pip (or pip3) at some point. You should attempt to uninstall the version of catkin_pkg that was installed through pip:

```
pip uninstall catkin_pkg
```

(if you installed as root, you may need to run the unistall with `sudo`).

Note that this **will not** remove the version of catkin_pkg that was installed through apt (which is good)

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-01-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Albatross](https://answers.ros.org/users/4920/albatross/) on 2016-01-11**:
Thanks! I've got it working now. Uninstalling with pip or pip3 didn't fix it (got a message saying it couldn't find anything to uninstall) so what I ended up doing was just renaming the file in /usr/local/bin to something else so it wouldn't use that one.

**Comment by [Albatross](https://answers.ros.org/users/4920/albatross/) on 2016-01-11**:
I checked the date on catkin_create_pkg from /usr/local, turns out it was created in 2013, so it must have been from when I was mucking around with ROS in the past. I thought I uninstalled all of the old stuff and replaced it with the new version, but it seems a few things were missed.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-01-11**:
If you have old files installed by pip in /usr/local, and you're certain you don't need them any more, it's safe to delete them. (That's probably the case here). You may want to look through /usr/local/bin and /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages for any other old ROS packages and remove them too.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you use Anaconda3 for Python you have a PATH to python3 interpreter in your .bashrc file. You can change it to python2 (/usr/bin..) for example and your problem will solved.

---

Originally posted by [Fisherman](https://answers.ros.org/users/41088/fisherman/) with karma: 11 on 2019-04-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1